# Compressing Bitmaps in Memory

Tags: android

I am creating an Activity that reads all images from the device. I use the following code

```
ContentResolver crThumb = context.getContentResolver();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    crThumb,
                    Long.parseLong(url),
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, options);
            return b;
```

I display these bitmaps, in a GridView, however after sometime my activity crashes as there is not enough memory. How can i compress the bitmap in memory, before reading it?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

You call BMP.docodeStream() twice

first call figures how much to compress

second call does the compression instance to memory as per outcome of call #1